# Eliminating the parameter for a linear equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric, substitution

I have a set of parametric equations that graphs as a straight line, but I can't figure out how to eliminate the parameter. When I plug in the $t=x/\cos^2$ value into the y equation, I can't simplify it out to anything useful. All help is appreciated!
The equations are as follows:

> $x=\cos^2t$
>
> $y=-2\sin^2t$

Comment: Graphing it using the t/x/y t-chart led me to getting a straight line. My main issue is eliminating the parameter and I haven't been able to simplify the "y=-2sin^2cos^2x" that I've been getting.

Comment: I reformatted your question to make it easier to read. (1) $t=x/\cos^2$ makes no sense whatsoever. (2) $\cos^2 t=x$ and $\sin^2 t = -y/2$. Do you know some relation between $\cos^2 t$ and $\sin^2 t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=\cos^2t$$

$$-\frac{y}{2} = \sin^2t$$

Adding the two equations, we obtain

$$x-\frac{y}{2}=1$$

Also note that, $$ 0 \leq x \leq  1$$
$$-2 \leq y \leq 0$$